# Template function returns wrong value while reading

Tags: c++, templates, fstream

I am trying to create class that reading and writing to the same file in c++ using template function and I'm trying to realize the function read() that reading a char or int and returns it and when i tried to run it i got number like -998324343 please help :)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>    
using namespace std;

template <class T>
class myFile
{
    ifstream  in;
    ofstream out;

public:
    myFile(char* fileName)
    {

        in.open(fileName);
        if (!in.is_open())
            throw"couldnt open file to reading";
        out.open(fileName);
        if (!out.is_open())
            throw"couldnt open file to writing";

        cout << read();
    }

    T read() {
        T x;
        in >> x;
        return x;
    }
};

int main()
{
    try {
        myFile<int> a("read.txt");
    }
    catch (char* msg) {
        cout << msg << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Also `myFile` should probably not be a class template...

Comment: my teacher asked me for template class..

Comment: @TalSahar firstly, you forgot to check if `in >> x` succeeded. Since it failed, the result was left with an unspecified value. I fiddled around, and found that reading the file succeeds if you don't open the `ostream` to the same file. I'm not quite sure if or why it would not allowed. Why not simply create a single `fstream`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `out` and `in` refer to the same file. So when this happens:

```
in.open(fileName);
if (!in.is_open())
    throw"couldnt open file to reading";
out.open(fileName);
```

Assuming `fileName` exists as a file, `out` will truncate the file, so it becomes empty. The subsequent `in >> x;` will fail (because the file is empty) and depending on the C++ standard you're compiling against, either `x` will get zeroed out (since C++11) or remain unmodified (until C++11). I'm assuming you're compiling pre-C++11, in which case what you see is whatever indeterminate value `x` was initialized with.

Not sure what you need `out` for, but you either want it to refer to a different file or open it in append mode.

Regardless of whether or not `out` is truncating the file, the `>>` operation can fail. If it fails, you will get garbage data (or `0`). So you need to check the result of that operation.

---

Note: Everywhere you are using `char*` you should be using `const char*`. The conversion from string literal to `char*` is deprecated (if you compiled with warnings enabled, you would see this).

Comment: Thanks i fixed it but i get the same problem when i try to read char.

Comment: @TalSahar Please don't edit your question based on responses. One question per question.